# Woo commerce Single Product Sidebar

Tags: sidebar, woocommerce-offtopic

Im trying to move the product summary from a single product, into the woo commerce sidebar?

Does anyone know how to go about this?

Would be forever grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean on your product category page: What if you remove (or comment out) the item description from your content-single-product.php, or use CSS - display:none; and place the code in your sidebar.php? Or whatever sidebar template file you are using for your products? If you don't have one set up, you can do this in you widgets section - create a sidebar. Then go into the php file.

content-single-product.php can be found in: wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php and the chunk of code you should be moving is:

```
    <div class="summary entry-summary">

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
    ?>
```

Comment: amazing! :) nearly there! do you know how i would adapt this to only apply the change to specific pages?

Comment: p.s ideally some would display normally and some as this is all :)thanks again so much